how to count the number of reactions of a post in a channel. pyTelegramBotAPI?
I'm trying to create a chatbot that will read the number of reactions and send them to me. In the pyTelegramBotAPI documentation, I found the message_reaction_count_handler and message_reaction_handler methods, but both of them do not work. There is almost no information on the Internet since this is a recent update.
import telebot
from telebot.types import *

TOKEN = 'token'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def message_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)

@bot.message_reaction_handler(func=lambda update: True)
async def message_reaction_handler(update: MessageReactionUpdated):
    print("Reaction update received:")
    print(f'Message ID: {update.message_id}')
    for reaction in update.reactions:
        print(f'Reaction: {reaction.type.type}, Count: {reaction.total_count}')

@bot.message_reaction_count_handler(func=lambda update: True)
async def message_reaction_count_handler(update: MessageReactionCountUpdated):
    print("Reaction update received:")
    print(f'Message ID: {update.message_id}')
    for reaction in update.reactions:
        print(f'Reaction: {reaction.type.type}, Count: {reaction.total_count}')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

The message_handler function is working
